# kinect sdk usage without a kinect camera

Tags: image-processing, kinect

Is it possible to use features of the kinect sdk without images captured from the kinect camera (for instance still images on the computer)?

[Here is a picture with points recognized from the kinect sdk face tracker](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/kinectsdkfacetracking/thread/34fce85c-e40c-4b0d-97f8-3e9654994df9). Similar to AAM mapping. 
If there is a way, can someone please supply a short code example - assuming input image path will return mapped points on that image.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried [OpenNI](http://www.openni.org/)?

Comment: If face tracking is your goal, there are multiple algorithms out there that could be used as reference.  The face tracked code the Kinect uses is also available in the `Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.FaceTracking` namespace, from the Kinect for Windows Developer Toolkit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, and there is a very simple reason.

Kinect does NOT CAPTURE AN IMAGE.

It combines:

- An Image
- A Depth-Map made with an infrared based sensor.

The SDK assumes all those elements to be there, coming from the Kinect hardware.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinect explains everything the Kinext offers, in terms of hardware.

This means that even when feeding it an image (which would be hard enough) you would miss the absolutely critical depth information that is actually also used in motion capturing.

Comment: "coming from the Kinect hardware" -> So this is mandatory? What if I've got an RGB image and a depth map from maybe a different sensor such as RealSense? Or data I'm reading from disk? No way of using the face tracking features with that?

Answer (score 0):

TomTom posted a valid answer.  However, if your scenario is that you need to run the SDK w/out having access to a physical sensor (e.g. you're on a train) or you want to process lots of data from other sensors, then you can use Kinect Studio.  Kinect Studio allows you to record all the sources coming off the Kinect sensor and save these files (warning:  file sizes are huge).  You can then playback these files as if it was live data coming from a physical sensor.  Not only is this great for doing dev/testing on a plane, but it can also streamline your development time (e.g. you don't have to stand up from your desk after hitting F5).